# Input, Output C Program

Tags: c, printf, scanf

So thats my programm: 
This program scans and prints numbers, but I want it to print "Mistake" if a character is entered. It produces an infinite loop if I put something like an "a" in. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void){
    printf("Enter a number: \n");
    int a;
    while(scanf("%d",&a)!=EOF){
        if(46<'a'<58){
        }
        else{
            printf("Mistake.");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("%d\n",a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are better off scanning per character instead per integer.

Comment: 46<'a'<58 is always true, even it would by 46<a<58. 46<somevar is allways 0 or 1, and 0 and 1 are both less than 58.

Comment: "I want it to print "Mistake" if a character is entered" -- `scanf( "%d", ... )` will **fail** if a character is entered, because a character is not matching input for `"%d"`. You won't even *enter* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot *chain* the relational operators in C. You need to change

```
 if(46<'a'<58){
```

to

```
if ((46 < 'a')  && ( 'a' < 58 )) {
```

to make it work.

That said, a `char` value is not a match for `%d` format specifier. You need to either

- use `%c` to scan the input as `char` and check the ASCII value
- use `%d` to scan the `int` input and check for the return value of `scanf()` for success. Also, in case `scanf()` fails for a non-`int` value, you need to clean up the input buffer before you loop again to avoid the infinite looping.

Answer (score 1):

Read input as a string with `fgets()`, then test it as needed.

Using `scanf("%d", ...)` returns 0, 1, or `EOF` when it fails, reads an `int` or end-of-file is detected.  Code could test that return value, but robust code simple does not use `scanf()`.

```
char buf[100];
while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
  int a;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d",&a) == 1) {
    printf("%d\n",a);
  } else {
    puts("Mistake.");
  }
}
```

`if(46<'a'<58)` does not work.  it first compares `46<'a'` which is `1`:true and then compares `1 < 58` which is also true.  [@124...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286893/input-output-c-program/36287925#comment60200618_36286893)

Answer (score 0):

`46 < 'a' < 58` is always true, because `46 < 'a'` evaluates to `1`, and then `1 < 58` evaluates to `1`. Also I suppose you want `a`, rather than `'a'`, which is actually a literal. Additionally, I think your code has some logical problems.

Here is the refined code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void){
    puts("Enter a number:");
    char a;
    while(scanf("%c", &a) != EOF) {
        if(('0' <= a && a <= '9') || a == '\n'){
            putchar(a);
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Mistake.");
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```